# Looping folders names from excel file vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that will copy the desired files that I want
here's the code

```
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim fname As String

saveFolder = "C:\Copied file"

folder = Workbooks("Macros.xlsb").Worksheets("folder").Range("A2")
FileName = Workbooks("Macros.xlsb").Worksheets("path").Range("B4")

Path = FileName & "\" & folder & "\Samples\*.xlsx"
file = Dir(Path)

Workbooks.Open Path

Sheets("Accounts").copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveFolder & "\Accounts.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
Workbooks(file).Close

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

it works well but I need to input manually the folder name in the cell column. But I'm clicking every after the macro is done for 1 folder only and so on.

I just want to know how to loop it.

this will be my worksheet(folder) for the folder names:

```
FOLDER
45
118
180
290
```

I want to loop the macro for each cells. so that I don't need to click/edit one by one the values. because the folder names can be changed momentarily.

Comment: Do you just want to copy Excel files from specified folders to "C:\Copied file" or you want do anything else as well?

Comment: @TanmayGawankar yes I just want to copy specified folders to "C:\Copied file" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the bounds of your question asking for a loop, you can try this ...

```
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim fname As String

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

' Set this either statically or dynamically.
lastRow = 100
saveFolder = "C:\Copied file"

' Start from where you want either statically or dynamically.
For i = 4 To lastRow
    folder = Workbooks("Macros.xlsb").Worksheets("folder").Range("A2")
    Filename = Workbooks("Macros.xlsb").Worksheets("path").Range("B" & i)

    Path = Filename & "\" & folder & "\Samples\*.xlsx"
    file = Dir(Path)

    Workbooks.Open Path

    Sheets("Accounts").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveFolder & "\Accounts.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    Workbooks(file).Close
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

for just copying files from one location to another, you do not need to open and saveAs on file :)

You can loop in folder names from top row to lastRow and process the folders one by one.
Find last row by
`lastRow = wb.sheets("Folder").cells(wb.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row`

Now, loop through the folder name by for loop
`for i=2 to lastRow`

you can have your folder inside the loop like

```
for i=2 to lastRow
    folder = Workbooks("Macros.xlsb").Worksheets("folder").Range("A" & i)
    ...
    copy  operations and filter here
    ...
next i
```